# What is proper way to create objects inside method using Guice

Tags: java, guice

What is proper way to create objects inside method of a Singleton object using Guice.

If I have some code like this below, what is a proper way to create instances of Class2? 
Class1 is singleton and need to create one new instance of Class2 everytime search is called (so I can not inject it with constructor field...) I will reorganize code if needed.

```
@Singleton
final class Class1 {

@Inject
private Class1(...){...}

public Class2 search(...){
   Class2 newInstance=...
   return newInstance;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess I found it.
Need to use providers for such instances.
Obtain class provider in constructor and use provider.get to obtain instances.

Something like:

```
@Singleton
final class Class1 {

Provider<Class2> p;

@Inject
private Class1(Provider<Class2> pParam;...){
p=pParam;
...
}

public Class2 search(...){
   Class2 newInstance=p.get();
   return newInstance;
}

}
```

Comment: If you need to provide parameters other than the injected ones, look into the assisted inject feature too, which lets you create a factory interface declaring that some args get passed to the object.